# Removing a pinned app's icon from the Windows 7 taskbar on the application's major upgrade with WiX

Tags: wpf, windows-7, wix, icons, taskbar

After removing a WPF application which were installed with WiX, the app's icon, previously pinned to the Windows 7 taskbar, have not been removed automatically. It remains orphaned and needs to be removed manually. Is it a supposed, typical behaviour?
The problem is that after a major upgrade of the application, the pinned icon remains inactive and needs to be manually deleted and repinned. It confuses some users.

Is there a possibility to delete or reactivate the app's icon, pinned to the Windows 7 taskbar, when doing an application major upgrade with WiX installer?

Comment: Are you worried about users who pinned it being confused, or did your installer cheat and pin it? For reference, Apple's iTunes has this problem for the former scenario, so it might be, ah, "acceptable behavior".

Comment: @MichaelUrman No cheat from the installer. I just wanted to make my installation process more polished; not to force a user think and not to force a user to do something additionally.

Comment: Okay, the party line answer is then that your installer has no knowledge about this shortcut so it can't be expected to fix it. Personally I think of this as a bug or limitation in the Windows shell experience; more of a bug if the target didn't move, more of a limitation if the major upgrade's target is in a new location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should rather change strategy: you need to set [`AppUserModelID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378459%28VS.85%29.aspx) on your shortcut. The value of this property should not change during upgrade. Then the shell, Windows Taskbar, will know to update its pinned shortcut.

You can read more on shortcut properties in [*Windows 7 Taskbar support with the `MsiShortcutProperty` table*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windows_installer_team/archive/2009/09/02/windows-7-taskbar-support-with-the-msishortcutproperty-table.aspx).

There's also a sample code in WiX which shows [how to set shortcut property](http://blogs.technet.com/b/alexshev/archive/2010/05/13/from-msi-to-wix-part-26-shortcut-to-pin-or-not-to-pin.aspx).

Comment: Although adding "System.AppUserModel.ID" to a Shortcut didn't help to refresh the icon which was previously pinned (I didn't manage to solve my initial issue, but maybe I missed something, so I'll try to explore the topic further), you pointed out the whole lot of useful information to me. Thanks, a lot! +1

Comment: @rem Unfortunately you can't fix the previous icon: that would require a time machine. There's no public API you can use to control pinned applications. The only thing you can try is to delete your shortcut from Taskbar pinned icon “cache”: %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar\.