# How to update app icon pinned to taskbar when updating with WiX installer

Tags: wpf, wix, windows-10, windows-installer, installation

I have a wpf application with a WiX installer and here's my issue. If two users have the application pinned to their Task Bar. If user A upgrades the installed version from version x to version y, version y's new icon appears on the taskbar for user A, but it does NOT for user B. The old taskbar icon is still present for user B.

I found this other answer that seemed kind of relevant but it's rather old, just wondering if there's some tribal knowledge or something I'm juts completely unaware of to solve this issue of the icon on the taskbar not updating for other users after a software update done through wix for a wpf application.

The only issue I have with this answer is that it's windows 7 and we're using 10 and support 10.

[Removing a pinned app's icon from the Windows 7 taskbar on the application's major upgrade with WiX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8909736/removing-a-pinned-apps-icon-from-the-windows-7-taskbar-on-the-applications-maj?rq=1)

any thoughts?  If this is a duplicate of another question or something I can delete it, I just feel I've done a sufficient amount of searching and am close to just not worrying about this anymore.

Comment: About 3 months ago I tried to develop a custom Wix action to pin unpin icons. Just forget it, won't work for Windows 8 and 10. It only worked for Win7.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, It seems that the best course of action so far is to just let the users handle if it they feel they want the new icon..